# Regex to match `99` but not `!99`

Tags: ruby, regex

My string is: `"1 !2 3"`. I need to match all numbers except `!2`. I tried `/\b\d{1,5}\b/`, but it still matches `!2`. The `\b` anchor works well with words, but not digits.

What is the regex to solve my problem?

Comment: In regex, a "word" character can be a letter, a digit or an underscore.

Answer (score 4):

You need a negative lookbehind `(?<!!)` and use the word boundaries around `\d+` (to exclude partial matches on 2+ digit numbers):

```
"1 !2 3".scan(/(?<!!)\b\d+\b/)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/lmKrTF) and a [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/tG9eU8/1). If you really plan to match numbers consisting of 1 to 5 digits, replace `+` quantifier (1 or more occurrences) with your `{1,5}` limiting quantifier.

The `(?<!!)` fails the match if a digit is preceded with an exclamation mark. The word boundaries require a non-word character on both sides of the digit chunks matched with `\d+`. As a `!` is a non-word character (i.e. it belongs to the `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` character range), it is allowed if you just use a word boundary - that is why your regex did not work. Adding the lookbehind solves the issue.

Comment: Do you need the second word break?  I think `/(?<!!\d*)\d+/` also works.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I do not believe the current Ruby's regex engine supports infinite-length lookbehind, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/EHQ3k5).

Comment: Ah, yes. The little grey cells let me down (again).

Comment: Just to help understand Wiktor's correct answer, These are from Perl's own regex definitions:
() = "Results are remembered. Used for partial matches/subpatterns"
? = "Matches zero or any char/extends the meaning of/Accept as {0,1}"
< = "Look behind (iterate) to find previous patterns"
The () symbols make sure it is only the per-instance previous use of the '!' symbol that that the 'look-behind' method is used on.
Use with caution as a '<' symbol combined with a '+' symbol can cause endless looping of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex that doesn't have a lookbehind:

```
r = /
    \s*!\d+\s* # match >= 0 spaces, an exclamation mark, > 0 digits, >= 0 spaces
    |          # or
    \s+        # match > 0 spaces
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode

"1 !2 3".split(r)
  #=> ["1", "3"]
```

or two regexes:

```
"1 !2 3".gsub(/!\d+/, "").scan(/\d+/)
  #=> ["1", "3"]
```

or no regexes:

```
"1 !2 3".split.reject { |s| s.start_with?("!") }
  #=> ["1", "3"]
```

Comment: Creative ways to solve the problem! I prefer REGEX, but sometimes we need to split the problem among other functions.